# How do I use CIN to read values from a file (64 bit integer)

Tags: c++, stl

Let's say I have the file input.txt containing the following numbers :

```
2 1 1 888450282
1 2
```

I need to read the first line in separate variables (a,b,c,d).
The big value can be big like a 64 bit integer. How do I use C++ IO to do this?
And the second line can have 1 to N values.

Normally I do this in C but I want to learn the C++ library and I'm also not very confortable with 64 bit integers in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only concerned about the first line of the file you can use something like the following to get it.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
```

And the following code will handle the file.

```
    ifstream file("yourfile.txt", ios::in);
    int a, b, c;
    long long d;
    file >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    printf("a: %d, b: %d, c: %d, d: %lld", a, b, c, d);

    file.close();
```

Comment: Alright thanks, this is exactly the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You use iostream in the usual way, i.e. read it into a 64-bit-sized integer:

```
 #include <stdint.h>

 uint64_t value;
 std::cin >> value;
```

BTW, you could also use stdio in the form

```
 #include <inttypes.h>
 #include <stdint.h>

 uint64_t value;
 fscanf(file, "%"PRiu64"", &value);
```

Comment: stdint is for GCC ? I use Visual Studio

Comment: @toto: `stdint.h` is for C99. For MSVC, check http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/.